# Can't access private field with Type.GetMember in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, reflection

The following code fails to find private fields, for example if **host** is `Application.Current` and **member** is "_ownDispatcherStarted", it returns an empty array, but if if I look for a private property, for example member is "ParkingHwnd", it returns an array of length 1; it finds it ok.  Why is that?

```
        var hostType = host.GetType();
        var members = host.GetType()
            .GetMember(member, Public | NonPublic | Instance);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did some experimentation. According to the documentation, you need to specify `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` in order to exclude inherited members, but in my tests, I found that I could not get inherited members to appear in returned values from `GetMember`, `GetFields` or `GetField`.

With a default WPF application, `Application.Current` is not an instance of `Application` directly, but of the subclass of `Application` defined in `App.xaml`. I found that if I used `host.GetType().BaseType`, then fields such as `_ownDispatcherStarted` were discoverable.

So, in order to generically find fields declared by the `Application` base class, you may need to walk up the inheritance tree, repeatedly following `BaseType` until you either find the member you're looking for or hit the root.

This isn't the result I expected, but hopefully it'll get you going. :-)

Comment: Good catch. I tried this and got nowhere. I was passing in the `FlattenHierarchy` flag, but it turns out that won't get you inherited private fields: "Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be returned"

Comment: Yeah, `FlattenHierarchy` is for static members. The documentation implies that instance members should be included by default, and you can opt out of having them included with `DeclaredOnly` -- but my testing did not show that result.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, this gives me another dimension to work on.  I see what you mean about `Application.Current` the actual type is `MyApplicationNamespace.App`